# How can I efficiently check if a given email address is included in a distribution list in Microsoft Outlook OWA?

Tags: email, outlook-on-the-web, mailing-list

From what I can see, clicking on the distribution list in Microsoft Outlook OWA doesn't give any efficient way to check if a given email address is included in a distribution list, since would have to go through the list of email addresses included in a distribution list (which is inconvenient if the distribution list contains many email addresses):

[image]

[image]

How can I efficiently check if a given email address is included in a distribution list in Microsoft Outlook OWA?

Comment: I'm still interested in this question.

Comment: If anyone has any idea, welcome!